# "para-" in words like "paraglider" and "parabrake"

Tags: prefixes, greek

As is well known, *para-*, in its meaning of "alongside or beyond", is derived from Greek loanwords such as *paraphrase* and *parasite*, while its meaning of "against" is derived from the Latin "be prepared" as in *parachute* and *parasol*.

My question is: From where is *para-* derived in words like, for example, *parabrake* and *paraglider*? Can *parachute* itself be the source of the prefix "para-" in these words?

The scope of the question is to investigate whether grammarians recognize only two roots for the *para-* words, or, instead, they recognize three roots, the last one having evolved independently in modern English.

Comment: Your standards are slipping, @Carlo! I didn't even *know* the word "parabrake" until now, but it takes only a couple of seconds to establish that it's *another name for brake parachute*. And obviously *paragliding* has the same roots as ***parachuting***. And I know from your earlier question that you're aware of the etymology for that *(**para-** "defense against" + **chute** "a fall")*.

Comment: 'Para' **appears** in loanwords and later analogues, and has many more meanings than "alongside or beyond", and "against". At http://www.reference.com/motif/reference/prefix-para the meanings _near_, _resembling_, _apart from_, and _abnormal_ are added.

Comment: Another use of *para* is as a shortening of the word paratrooper. It's used informally. *Para* is singular and *paras* is plural.

Comment: Once a word has become familiar enough, it gets frozen and pieces of it can be sliced off and used as roots for other words. Like _helico-pter_ (Greek 'spiral wing'), which got fused and rebroken into _heli-copter_, as in _helipad_ and _cargo copter_. So the _para_- in _parachute_ gets appropriated for other words.

Comment: parachute comes directly from French.  In French, para- is used quite often for the sense of 'defense against'.  Parasol = defense against sol (sun), parapluie = defense against pluie (rain) aka umbrella.  So to your question, there may be 4 origins - Latin by way of French the fourth.

Answer (score 9):

*Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) reports six distinct senses of the prefix *para-* (or *par-*):

> **1:** beside: alongside of: beyond: aside from <*para*thyroid> **2a:** closely related to <*par*aldehyde> **b:** involving substitution at or characterized by two opposite positions in the benzene ring that are separated by two carbon atoms <*para*dichlorobenzene> **3a:** faulty: abnormal <*par*esthesia> **b:** associated in a subsidiary or accessory capacity <*para*medical> **c:** closely resembling: almost <*para*typhoid>.

In addition, the Eleventh Collegiate lists one combining form of *para-*:

> **para-** *comb form* [*parachute*]: parachute

But it doesn't list another combining form that is evident from the opening portion of the dictionary's entry for *Paralympics*:

> **Paralympics** *n pl* [*para*plegic + O*lympics*]

**Note:** As Avon points out in a comment below, the International Paralympic Committee, which organizes the Paralympic Games, now presents the word *paralympic* as referring not to *paraplegic* but to *parallel*. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paralympic_Games) on these games explains the change:

> Although the name was originally coined as a portmanteau combining "paraplegic" (due to its origins as games for people with spinal injuries) and "Olympic," the inclusion of other disability groups meant that this was no longer considered very accurate. The present formal explanation for the name is that it derives from the Greek preposition παρά, *pará* ("beside" or "alongside") and thus refers to a competition held in parallel with the Olympic Games.

I couldn't find any non-proper nouns in the dictionary that use *para-* as a combining form with the meaning "paraplegic," but a Google search reveals that some parts of Alberta and Yukon Territory in Western Canada use the term *pararamp* to refer to wheelchair-friendly sidewalk-to-street ramps on city streets. Since these are not alternatives to some sort of normal ramp (normally, sidewalks end in curbs that drop off to the street several inches below), I don't think that any of the six senses of *para-* that the Eleventh Collegiate identifies apply here. If that's correct, then the *para-* in *pararamp* would seem to be short for *paraplegic* or *paralytic*.

The same cannot be said for *paratransit* and *paratransport*, which refer to services that are ancillary to the standard transit and transport options in the municipalities that offer them. Of course, many people who have difficulty with standard mass-transit options are neither paraplegic nor wheelchair-bound; but I suspect that the coiners of *pararamp* may have been influenced by their awareness that paratransit and paratransport do offer special services for people in wheelchairs.

In any event, as FumbleFingers says, *parabrake* and *paraglider* (like *paratrooper*) fall into the combining form of *para-* that signifies 'parachute." A final point: The words *parasol*, *parachute*, and *paravane* (referring to "a torpedo-shaped protective device with serrate teeth in its forward end used underwater by a ship in mined areas to sever the moorings of mines") use *para-* in the sense of "to ward off or to shield"; in the context of *parachute*, the Eleventh Collegiate says, *chute* means "fall."

Comment: Paralympics is short for Parallel Olympics (beside/alongside of the Olympics) not from Paraplegic Olympics (the entrants aren't generally paraplegic). http://www.infoplease.com/spot/summer-olympics-paralympics.html It's a bit shocking that Merriam-Webster should make that mistake.

Comment: @Avon: I suspect that MW was reporting the original derivation—not the current attribution—of the name. According to the Wikipedia article on [Paralympic Games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paralympic_Games), "Although the name was originally coined as a portmanteau combining 'paraplegic' (due to its origins as games for people with spinal injuries) and 'Olympic,' the inclusion of other disability groups meant that this was no longer considered very accurate. The present formal explanation for the name is that it ... refers to a competition held in parallel with the Olympic Games."

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks Sven. In that case +1

Answer (score 2):

A very quick search would show that the roots of "paraglider" and "parabrake" are completely separate from the "para" (alongside) roots which you suspect.

The direct answer to your question is, yes, they derive from "parachute".

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paragliding#History

Both words are portmanteau words, combining, for instance, parachute and glider.

The development of the parachute, especially after WWII, showed the possibility of parachutes with significant glide ratios, and by 1961 paragliding was established as a term. An early example of the modified parachute was the Para-Commander.

Answer (score 2):

**Question 1**

> Can parachute itself be the source of the
>   prefix "para-" in these words?

**Answer**

Yes, in one of them. It is in the case of parabrake.

> **parabrake** (ˈpærəˌbreɪk Pronunciation for parabrake  )
>
> Definitions
>
> noun  another name for **brake parachute**
>
> [Collins Dictionary](http://public.oed.com/aspects-of-english/english-in-use/the-gate-suffix/)
>    [1](http://public.oed.com/aspects-of-english/english-in-use/the-gate-suffix/): http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/parabrake

The word is a clear derivation from the longer term.

However this is not directly so for **paraglider**.

> Origin of paraglider para(foil) + glider.
>
> The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, 5th edition

Paraglider comes from parafoil which, in turn comes from parachute.

> Definition of **PARAFOIL** :  a self-inflating fabric device that
>   resembles a **parachute**, behaves in flight like an airplane wing, is
>   maneuverable, is capable of landing a payload at slow speed, and can
>   be launched from the ground in a high wind like a kite
>   http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parafoil

**Question 2**

> The scope of the question is to investigate whether grammarians
>   recognize only two roots for the para-words, or, instead, they
>   recognize three roots, the last one evolved independently in modern
>   English.

**Answer**

I think so, yes. For example we often see news items with "-gate" appended to them. Here is a discussion of the phenomenon:

> The ‘gate’ suffix
>
> - In 1972 the United States was transfixed by the revelation that the
>     burglary at the national headquarters of the Democratic Party was
>     connected with Richard Nixon’s Republican government. The burglary
>     took place in the Watergate building, Washington DC, and thus, by
>     metonymy, the scandal itself became known by the name of Watergate.
>     One of the most significant episodes in modern US politics, Watergate
>     has since reshaped the language of scandal and controversy in a format
>     that also extends beyond English-speaking commentaries.*
>
> By Eleanor Maier, [OED](http://public.oed.com/aspects-of-english/english-in-use/the-gate-suffix/)

You can see that this article was written by an employee of the Oxford English Dictionary - an authoritative source if ever there was one.

Clearly there was nothing about the suffix "gate" that indicated scandal before Watergate. So I think it is safe to say that the etymology of all such scandals is derived from the name Watergate rather than from the word 'gate'.

In the same way it is clear that "para" does not directly mean "be prepared" when it is used in 'paraglider'.  The word 'parachute' is the origin via parafoil.

However, when we come to 'parabrake', it could be argued either way. A parabrake **may** be used in an emergency and hence be a sign of preparedness. However in general parabrakes are used routinely, e.g. to slow down drag racers, re-entering space-craft and so on.  They are primarily brakes rather than emergency equipment.

**Conclusion**

I think it safe to say that 'para' in parabrake derives directly from parachute and not from a Latin or Greek root. However in paraglider the etymology comes via parafoil which is itself a derivation from parachute.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is yes if the *OED* is a good enough authority for you.  The original *OED* recognized two type of prefixes, which it called "Para-<sup>1</sup>" and "Para-<sup>2</sup>".  The former was from the Greek *παρ*-, *παρα*- meaning "beside," which (as you note) gives us "paraphrase"; the latter, from the Latin *parare*, to defend against, which gives us via French the word "parachute," a defense against a fall.

The last paper supplement to the *OED* adds a"Para-<sup>3</sup>" defined as a "Comb[ining] form of Parachute."  Examples of its use include "parabrake" (a parachute that opens at the back of an aircraft and that acts as a break) and "paraglider" (a device that lets it operator fly like a glider and descend safely to earth like a parachutist).

Clearly neither of the original definitions will do.  A parabrake is not something that stands along side a brake or defends against a brake.  It's a type of parachute and its name derives from that device.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The word parachute is derived from **para-² + chute**. Whereas parabrake and paraglide is derived from **para-³ + brake** and **glide** respectively.

**[para-²:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/para-)** *combining form* indicating an object that acts as a protection against something: parachute, parasol.
[**Origin**: French, from Italian, from *parare* to shield, ultimately from Latin *parāre* to prepare]

**[para-³:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/para-)** *combining form* extracted from [parachute](http://www.britannica.com/dictionary/parachute), forming compounds denoting persons or things utilizing parachutes or landed by parachute: paradrop; paradoctor; paraglider; paratrooper.

Answer (score 0):

The *para-* in *parachute* comes ultimately from Italian (or from Latin, if you want to go back that far). Random House Webster's Unabridged Dictionary provides this definition for the prefix *para-*:

> a combining form meaning "guard against," occurring in loan words from
>   French, or, via French, from Italian: parachute, parasol. [< F < It
>   *para*, 3d sing pres of *parare* to prepare against, ward off < L *parare* to PREPARE]

Spanish makes heavier use of the *para-* prefix with words like:

- *paraguas* to fend off waters (in other words, *rain*) an umbrella
- *parasol* to fend off the sun
- *parabrisas* to fend off breezes, i.e. a windshield

Comment: Not just Spanish—French (and I presume Italian) does too: _parapluie_ (‘stop-rain’, an umbrella), _parasol_ (as in Spanish), and _pare-brise_ (as in Spanish).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Italian has *parafuoco* as a fire-stopper or fire-ward and *paravento* for (another) wind-stopper. There’s also a Spanish parachute, a *paracaídas*, which keeps you from falls/falling, along with a *parachoques, parafango, paragranizo, pararrayos*,  and various others. Given that *parar* is used for a simple “stop” verb— *¡Para!* — it’s easy to think of a *parathing(s)* as a ”thing-stopper”: a water-stopper, a sun-stopper, a wind-stopper, etc. You could equally have a *quitasol* or a *quitaguas* etc. But I don’t truly believe *parapets* were originally meant as cat-doors. :)

Comment: How does this answer the question? The question already explicitly says that *para* can mean "*against*", as in *parachute* and *parasol*. The question asks about *paraglider* and *parabrake*, where it seems that the prefix does not have this same meaning.